# Inconsistent results formatting SharePoint column with JSON

Tags: json, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I am working with library catalog items that may have 2 different URLs for each item.  I have two plain text columns, each containing one of the URLs.

I have two additional columns I am formatting as hyperlinks based of the URL text columns.  I am using the same code (with different column names) for each field formatted as a URL.  One link column works, the other does not.

This is a screenshot of the list with all four fields displayed.  You can see the text URL fields and fields formatted as URL (one working, one not).  I do not believe it is related to the URL syntax - I have tried pasting the same URL in both fields, but get the same results (one working, one not).

[image]

This is the code from the column that works:

[image]

This is the code from the column that does not work:

[image]

Column type is the same.  (The formatted link field needs to be a number for some odd reason.)

[image]

Can anyone help me figure out why?

Answer (score 0):

1 - Did you check their internal names ? In the list settings, you may click on each field and on their respective pages, in the URL at the end, you will find their Internal Name. You may find there that the one not working has a slightly different name ?

2 - Have you tried opening your navigator developer tools (F12) while editing/saving your JSON schema to see if there's a JavaScript error ?

3 - Have you tried on a third test column ?

Comment: Thank you!  It was the internal name.

Comment: Mark it as answered please, so everyone knows your issue is resolved

Comment: For future reference: you can get the internal name of your SharePoint columns by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)